# Number of partitions of $n$ with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Find the ordinary generating function for the number of partitions of n in which all parts are odd and none surpasses 7. My answer is:

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^7 \frac{1}{1-x^{2i}}$$

She is correct?

Comment: Looks like the number of partitions where all parts are even and none surpasses $14$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** See this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts). The generation function is $\large{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^{2i-1}}}=\normalsize{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}}(1-x^i)$. For $n=7$ we get

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{7}(1-x^i)$$